# Jquery not detecting multi select form elements

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5.4

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple categories  form-control" name="categories[]" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="fresher">fresher</option>
    <option value="experienced"> experienced</option>
</select>
```

multi select control in the form.

```
console.log($("#new-job-form").serialize());
```

is showing all other form elements in console.

```
_token=5eDJlHTMLybD73xyW4C0wdXjYrsL3xJa5CsxrwYS&_method=POST&company_id=1&job_title=
```

When i remove `multiple="multiple"`, name="categories[]" element is being detected.

Also if i select a value in categories then also element getting detected.

```
_token=5eDJlHTMLybD73xyW4C0wdXjYrsL3xJa5CsxrwYS&_method=POST&company_id=1&job_title=&categories%5B%5D=
```

Now I'am not able to validate categories field in controller as there is no categories key in request array.

```
'categories.*' => 'required',
```

Comment: Could you post the actual client-side code that is generated? (View source in browser).

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/7jdeohxh/1

Comment: @cjs1978 I changed it in the question

Comment: @charlietfl but mine is not working.please do try with the updated code in the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to check those things.

```
- Clear view cache.
- Your jquery is included in head tag.?
- Make some changes in form and check the changes is effect in web console Element Tab.?
- check Form id and jQuery select element id is same.?
- Put dd($request); in your controller method and check parameter is received.?
```

Here is my code and this code tested and working on my PC.

1.) Define route in `web.php`

```
Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@store')->name('home.store');
```

2.) HTML Form

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" id="form_sbtn">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple categories  form-control" name="categories[]" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="fresher">fresher</option>
        <option value="experienced"> experienced</option>
    </select>
    <button name="sbtn" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

3.) Ajax form

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=sbtn]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefalut();
        $.ajax({
            url : "{{ route('home.store') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data : $("#form_sbtn").serialize(),
            success : function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error : function(error){

            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

4.) Controller public method.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Comment: cleared cache and view in storage. All other fileds are being detected even when there is no value.  In the form itself categories is not detected then how we will get it in the controller?

Comment: i think you are not getting me .$("#form_sbtn").serialize() doesn't contains categories select field unless you chosse a value.I have already tried that dd(); The issue is with the view blade.https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/653

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/653

I think the issue is  not solved yet...

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#new-job-form").validate({

        rules: {

              'categories[]': {
                  required: true,
              }
          },

          messages: 
          {
              'categories[]': {
                  required: "Please provide categories"
              }
          }
      });
```

Try this one

Comment: Server  side validation required

Comment: Please mention in question client side or server code you want.